# Адаптивность JS

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Есть меню-сендвич, который выезжал вниз на контент, чтобы этого не случилось при клике на меню добавил padding-top  у этого самого контента. Встал вопрос - возможно ли адаптивность на строить,к примеру на ниже 1200 разрешении padding-top: 430px , на ниже 978 - padding-top: 330px и т.д.

P.S. У owl-carousel нечто подобное есть, через опции задается. Помогите дописать, сам не могу разобраться.

```
// TOGGLE MNU MOBILE SANDWICH
$(".toggle-mnu").click(function() {
    $(".sandwich").toggleClass("active");
}); 

$(".toggle-mnu").click(function() {
    if ($(".hidden-mnu").is(":visible")) {
        $(".hidden-mnu").slideUp();
        $(".doc-info").css('padding-top', '430px');
    } else {
        $(".hidden-mnu").slideToggle();
        $(".doc-info").css('padding-top', '668px');
    }

});

// Пример с OWL.Carousel
responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:1
        },
        1000:{
            items:1
        }
    }
```

Comment: Можешь попробовать не задавать padding через js, а просто навешивать css класс на элемент, например opened и уже в css, при помощи media queries, задавать разные отступы в зависимости от ширины и ориентации экрана.

Comment: Точно! даже в голову не приходило :(